# Firebase servers not reachable when using mobile phone data (3g/4g)

Tags: mobile, firebase, wifi, firebase-realtime-database

I was running some FireBase tests and suddenly I realized Firebase was not working anymore when using mobile data from Chile. At the beginning I thought the problem was my app so I tried to open a Firebase official example but I had no luck (office-mover-demo example). This is what I tried:

I connected the phone to my home wifi connection and FireBase works :)
I shared the phone’s internet connection to my computer and it did not work :( . This is the error y receive.

I emailed Firebase support and they sill don´t have an answer  to this strange situation. I asked people from The Netherlands and Mexico City to try and realized the problem was only happening in Chile :o . It’s like FIrebase URLS (http://firebase.com  , firebaseapp.com ) are not reachable from Chile using mobile data plans!  Does anybody have any clue ?[IMAGE OF THE JAVASCRIPT CONSOLE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtdNM.png)

Comment: *firebaser here* It seems your mobile operator is blocking traffic to firebaseio.com. There is not much Firebase support nor the community of developers here on Stack Overflow can do to help with that.

Comment: Hi Frank, we tested it out with 5 different mobile providers. I don´t think all companies have any reason to block Firebase.

Comment: @JuanAndres I also have the same problem. Do you already fix it? It was your provider? In my case I'm using WOM.

Comment: this question almost 2 years ago. still, I  have same problem in 2020. is there any solution?

Comment: I'm facing this problem too in late 2023. Any solution so far?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in egypt/vodafone 3g both in iOS and web too, for now am using VPN apps, once I turn on vpn firebase DB starts working :D :D

looks like it has to do with web sockets.