# Firebase verification SMS not working on many phones

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase phone authentication in my Android App.. It works fine. But SMS is not received on many phones, specifically 3g phones. 4g compatible phone work fine. What could be the reason? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973945/firebase-servers-not-reachable-when-using-mobile-phone-data-3g-4g